# List all links of one website on other website

Tags: website, url, web-crawler

There are two websites.

```
1) www.aa.com
2) www.bb.com
```

Now there are so many link of aa.com and its webpages on bb.com 
like

```
aa.com/blhahhaa.html
aa.com/beautifulday.html
aa.com
```

so i want to find out that list.

So is there any scripts or tool available for that?
any idea how to develope such tool?

This is something how google crawl all website but here i want to crawl one website only.

Comment: Product advice questions are off topic. It also reads as if you've done no research. Yes doing this is possible, but you'll probably need to learn a language if you don't find a script (I write these applications often in .NET)

Answer (score 2):

If you run on Linux I would use Bash script reading page with [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) and parsing it looking for links, then crawl that links. Use Google for it, there's pleanty of ready made scripts.

If on Windows I would use yours any preferable language with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) extension to get page contents instead of `wget`. If you read wiki page it's "See also" page even directing to `wget`. Dig on it.

PS That question of yours seems little lazy.